# Can a switch statement be used on Control objects passed to an event handler?

Tags: c#, event-handling, switch-statement, controls, sender

I have multiple controls that share the same event handler. Instead of writing a series of

```
if(sender == specific_control)
{
     // do something
}
```

Is there a way I could use a switch statement or something similar instead?

When I type `switch(sender)` I get an error message that says

> A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, intergral, enum, or corresponding nullable type.

Comment: Convert to a string or enum value. Then you can use a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the event handler to do something different depending on which control raised the event, why are you using the same handler for each control? Just give each control its own handler method.

If there is some common code to execute when handling all of the different events, put *that* into a single method that can be called by the various event handler methods.

If the above advice does not seem applicable to your scenario, please improve your question so that it's clear why it's not. Be sure to include [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If these controls are of the same types, then you can use the "Type" of the control to generate a switch statement:

```
//Just a snippet, you can use the FullName or Name to determine which
//control it belongs to...
        Type t = (sender).GetType();
        switch (t.FullName)
        {
            case "Namespace.Control1":
                break;
            case "Namespace.Control2":
                break;
        }
```